# JSON VS XML : Theory Definition

Tags: xml, json

Does anyone know when XML should be used instead of JSON and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**XML - pros**

1. More strict - can be supplied along with Document Type Definition (DTD) which would allow you to analyze if provided XML data is syntactically correct
2. Namespaces - can help to mix data from various resources (for instance you can use namespaces from Spring Core and Spring Security, which helps to read and understand markup)
3. Can be navigated with XPath - helps to speed up looking for something deeply nested within markup
4. Huge sets of data can be parsed via lightweight processor like SAX parser
5. Used in some protocols (like SOAP) which could enforce using XML over JSON
6. Longer around the block - some older libraries can/use
7. Nice tools support (like native usage in Scala or IDE support)

**XML - cons**

1. Hard to read when it's getting really big - harder to maintain
2. Comes with an overhead from all unnecessary tags (like `<some_long_tag_name>...</some_long_tag_name>` ecountered x1000 times in one file) which can have huge impact on network bandwith and disk usage

**JSON - pros**

1. Easier to read by humans
2. Native support in web browsers thanks to `JavaScript`

**JSON - cons**

1. Doesn't contain type definition (`"some_object" : "10" // String or Int?`)
2. Lack of some sort of DTD (how can you tell that "some_object" is required?)

These are just major ones. Honestly one could write a book about it, so I don't wonder whay are people downgrading this question... However I found appropriate to help you out a little.

Comment: I've got to disagree with your type definition con for JSON - [the JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) allows for strings or numbers - if you quote a numeric value, it's explicitly a string, not a number.

Comment: Ok, won't argue with that. It's just that still there is no type definition attached to data, so there is always ambiguity when it comes down to figuring out type. This is especially true when dealing with `int` and `longs`. As far as I know there is way to distinguish int and long.

Answer (score 2):

Examples when (at the present state of tools, libraries, methods and knowledge) XML is preferred:

- Validation according to some rules (XSD, Relax NG)
- Communication with established (or *legacy* as some might say) systems through SOAP or REST/XML
- Digital signature based on W3C standards (XML Signature) or Oasis standards (WS-Security)
- When some might need presentation using some external *recipes* - XSLT
- When you need to generate PDFs using XSL with e.g., Apache FOP
- When you need to configure .NET applications using its standard web/application.config files
- When you just want to get your job done instead of following the herd

Comment: +1 for PL for not downgrading ;)